# I'm having a CORS Prefetch Error 400 Bad Request

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, cors

I am running a Vue project on my local dev server with a firebase function also running on local dev. Whenever I try to make a fetch request to my "beckend" I get a CORS error.

**PREFLIGHT REQEUST**

```
OPTIONS /api/url HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

**RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
x-powered-by: Express
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8080
access-control-allow-methods: POST, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 44
etag: W/"2c-1mdAJaORqKZ8xUSbM/cjasU4RC0"
date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 14:40:25 GMT
connection: keep-alive
keep-alive: timeout=5
```

Here's my code:

**FRONTEND**

```
fetch(/api/url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    currency: "usd",
    paymentMethodType: "card",
    amount: 1880,
  }),
}).then();
```

**BACKEND**

```
exports.myFunctionName = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const origin = req.headers.origin;

  if (ALLOWED_ORIGINS.includes(origin)) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  }

  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

  const {paymentMethodType, currency, amount} = req.body;
    const params = {
      payment_method_types: [paymentMethodType],
      amount: +amount,
      currency: currency,
    };

  try {

   // Create a PaymentIntent with the amount, currency, and a payment method type.
   const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(params);

    // Send publishable key and PaymentIntent details to client
    res.status(200).json({
      clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: {
        message: e.message,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

[image]
I can't seem to figure this out, I've been working at it for a few hours. Can anyone help?

Comment: you're not showing the part of your backend code that decides to return a 'bad request'. just the part where you add the headers.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I updated the code to show the rest of the function. However it isn't even being ran because it fails CORS. It is the preflight OPTIONS request that is getting a 400

Comment: No, it fails cors because it returns a 400 because `await stripe.paymentIntents.create(params);` (likely) errored out. What's the message inside of the 400 response?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas No response data is sent back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your function treats the preflight request as if it were the actual `POST` request, but they're separate and not sent simultaneously.

The browser automatically sends the `OPTIONS` preflight request (which has no body) *before* the `POST`. Your function tries to pass non-existent body parameters from `OPTIONS` to the Stripe API, resulting in an exception caught by your `catch` handler, which responds with a `400`.

The [backend function should respond to `OPTIONS` with an ok status (e.g., `200`)](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) before the browser can send the `POST` request:

```js
exports.myFunctionName = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  // Handle preflight request
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    // allow `POST` from all origins for local dev
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    return res.sendStatus(200);

  } else {
    // Handle `POST` request here...
  }
}
```